# Using parameters in procedures

Tags: plsql, parameters, oracle11g

I need to create a procedure that receives as a parameter a month and a year.

Inside the procedure I need to have a query to retrieve some values, that will have to take in account the parameters received.

```
create or replace procedure GET_REVS(MONTH in VARCHAR2,YEAR in varchar2) is
SELECT
  *                 
FROM
  REVENUS_TABLE
  WHERE
      Y_CODE IN ('YEAR')  
  AND M_CODE  IN ()
```

Now, M_CODE  should have the values since the start of the year until the **month received by parameter**.

Example if i receive in as parameter for the month a 4 i want my select to like this AND `M_CODE  IN ('1','2','3','4')`

But if i receive MONTH = 3..  i need the select to have `AND M_CODE  IN ('1','2','3')`

So what is the best way to do the procedure in order to be able to do that?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What about `TO_NUMBER(M_CODE) <= TO_NUMBER(MONTH)`? Will that not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could cast both `M_CODE` and `MONTH` as numbers and use `BETWEEN` operator or just <=:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_revs(month IN VARCHAR2, year IN VARCHAR2) IS
BEGIN
  ....
  SELECT *
  FROM revenus_table
  WHERE y_code = year
  AND TO_NUMBER(m_code) BETWEEN 1 AND TO_NUMBER(month);
  ...
END;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. It works fine. How can i learn more and pratcise some exercises to know more about pls/sql?

Answer (score 1):

You can do some thing like below example to make your procedure more dynamic

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_revs (
   MONTH   IN   VARCHAR2,
   YEAR    IN   VARCHAR2
)
IS
   variable_name   table_name%ROWTYPE;
   v_sql           VARCHAR2 (1000)
      :=    'SELECT  * FROM   REVENUS_TABLE   WHERE      Y_CODE IN ('
     || MONTH
     || ')';
BEGIN
   IF MONTH = 4 THEN
      v_sql := v_sql || ' and M_CODE  IN (''1'',''2'',''3'',''4'')';
   END IF;

   IF MONTH = 3 THEN
      v_sql := v_sql || 'and M_CODE  IN (''1'',''2'',''3'')';
   END IF;

   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql
   INTO              variable_name;
END;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Just an alternative to think about.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_revs(month IN VARCHAR2, year IN VARCHAR2) IS
lv_in_clause VARCHAR2(100 CHAR);
p_ref sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  SELECT 'IN ('
    ||WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(A.NUM)
    ||')'
  INTO lv_in_clause
  FROM
    (SELECT ''''
      ||LEVEL
      ||'''' NUM,
      1 ID1
    FROM DUAL
      CONNECT BY LEVEL < to_number(MONTH)
    )A
  GROUP BY a.ID1;
  OPEN p_ref FOR 'SELECT *  
FROM revenus_table  
WHERE y_code = '|| year  
||' AND m_code '||lv_in_clause; 

END;
```